# Prove that $9^{n+1} - 8n- 9$ divisible by $64$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Prove that $9^{n+1} - 8n- 9$ divisible by $64$.

I was wondering if the same can be proved by congruency modulus. It can be done using induction or binomial theorem.

Can anyone prove it using congruences if possible?

Comment: Always remember, these kind of problems can be solved in three elementary ways. First induction second binomial theorem and third congruences but the core idea lies in congruences always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is divided by $8$ since $9=1$ mod $8$, we have $9^{n+1}-8n-9=9(9^n-1)-8n=9(9-1)(1+...+9^{n-1})-8n=9(8.(1+...+9^{n-1}))-8n$.  We have ${{9^{n+1}-8n-9}\over 8}=9(1+9+...+9^{n-1})-n$
is divided by $8$. This implies the result since it shows that $9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is divided by $8^2=64$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}9^{n+1}-8n-9&=(8+1)^{n+1}-8n-9\\&=8^{n+1}-\binom{n+1}18^n+\cdots+\binom{n+1}{n-1}8^2+\overbrace{\binom{n+1}n}^{=n+1}8+1-8n-9\\&=8^{n+1}-\binom{n+1}18^n+\cdots+\binom{n+1}{n-1}8^2\\&\equiv0\pmod{64}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

proof that $9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is always divisible by $64$ for all real positive values of $n$.
say $9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is a multiple of $x$, where $x$ is also a real positive integer.
$$
f_{n} = 9^{n+1}-8n-9
$$.
therefore.
$$
\begin{align}
f_{n+1} = 9^{n+2}-8(n+1)-9\\
f_{n+1} = 9^{n+1}×9-8n-8-9\\
\frac{f_{n+1}}{9} = 9^{n+1}-\frac{8n}{9}-\frac{17}{9}\\
\frac{f_{n+1}}{9}-\frac{64n}{9}-\frac{64}{9} = 9^{n+1}-8n-9\\
\frac{f_{n+1}}{9}-\frac{64n}{9}-\frac{64}{9} = f_{n}\\
f_{n+1}-64n-64 = 9*f_{n}\\
f_{n+1}-9*f_{n} = 64n+64\\
\text{divide by 64}\\
\frac{f_{n+1}-9f_{n}}{64} = n+1
\end{align}
$$.
since $n$ is a real positive integer, $f_{n}$ and $f={n+1}$ must also be a real positive integer.
therefore both $f_{n}$ and $f_{n+1}$ must be divisible by $64$ for $n+1$ to be a real positive integer.
$\frac{f_{n+1}-9*f_{n}}{64} = n+1$