# Prove that $9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is divisible by 64 where n is a natural number using proof by induction.

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I have been trying to complete this proof by induction and am stuck. Could someone please help me? Here is my working out.

Prove that $p(n): 9^{n+1}-8n-9$ is divisible by 64 where n is a natural number using proof by induction.

**Step 1:** Show that $p(1)$ is true
\begin{align*}
p(1) & = 9^2-8-9 \\
& = 81-17 \\ 
& = 64
\end{align*}
$64$ is divisible by $64$ so $p(1)$ is true.

**Step 2:** Show that $p(k)=>p(k+1)$ is true.

Assume $9^{k+1}-8k-9$ is divisible by $64$. So,
$$9^{k+1}-8k-9=64M$$
where M is a natural number.

Show $p(k+1)$ is divisible by $64$.
\begin{align*}
9^{k+2}-8(k+1)-9 & = 9\times9^{k+1}-8k-8-9 \\
& = (8+1)9^{k+1}-8k-9-8 \\
& = 8\times9^{k+1}+(9^{k+1}-8k-8)-9 \\
& = 64M + 8\times9^{k+1} - 8
\end{align*}

This is clearly not divisible by $64$, what have I done wrong or what am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $9^{n+1} - 8n- 9$ divisible by $64$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496818/prove-that-9n1-8n-9-divisible-by-64). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%249%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D-8n-9%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the assertion is true for $n = 1$.

$p(1)$ is true because
$$
9^{n + 1} - 8 n - 9 = 9^2 - 8 - 9 = 64
$$
which is divisible by 64.

Induction step: Suppose that $p(n)$ is true for some positive integer $n$.

Then
$$
9^{n + 1} - 8 n - 9 = 64 M,
$$
where $M$ is a positive integer.

To show that $p(n + 1)$ is true, we proceed as follows.

$$
T = 9^{n + 2} - 8 (n + 1) - 9
$$

We wish to prove that $T$ is divisible by 64.

Now, we rewrite $T$ as
$$
T = 9^{n + 1} \times 9 - 8 n - 8 - 9 = (8 + 1) 9^{n + 1} - 8 n - 8 - 9
$$

Thus,
$$
T = 8 \left( 9^{n + 1} \right) + 9^{n + 1} - 8 n - 8 - 9
$$

Hence, we find that
$$
T = 8 \left( 9^{n + 1} - 1 \right) + [9^{n + 1} - 8 n - 9]
= 8 \left( 9^{n + 1} - 1 \right) + 64 M
$$

By binomial expansion,
$$
9^{n + 1} - 1 = (8 + 1)^{n + 1} - 1 = \left[ 8^{n + 1} +
\left( \begin{array}{c}
      n + 1 \\
      1
 \end{array} \right) 8^n + \cdots + \left( \begin{array}{c}
      n + 1 \\
      n
 \end{array} \right) 8 + 1 \right] - 1 
$$

Thus,
$$ 9^{n + 1} - 1 = 8 L,$$
where $L$ is some positive integer.

Hence,
$$
T = 64 L + 64 M = 64 (L + M)
$$

Thus, we conclude that $p(n + 1)$ is true.

Using the principle of mathematical induction, we conclude that $p(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$. $\ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Comment: I didnt think you use binomial expansion. Thank you!

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

After you simplify to $64M + 8 \cdot 9^{k+1} - 8$, we can simplify further by noticing $$64M + 8 \cdot 9^{k+1} - 8 = 64M + 8(9^{k+1} - 1)$$ so it suffices to show that $9^{k+1} - 1$ is divisible by $8$. However, $$9^{k+1} - 1 = (8+1)^{k+1} - 1 = -1 + \sum_{i=0}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}8^i = \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}8^i = 8\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom{k+1}{i}8^{i-1}$$ which is divisible by $8$.

Comment: Thank you I had not thought of this!

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).